# Messeging center hits multiple times when sending from Shared code to platform code- Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know these questions asked several times on SO. But I can't able to solve this. In my xamarin.forms app, I am showing a camera inside one page using custom Camera View. The button for taking a picture is in a shared code. For taking a picture from shared code, I am using the Messaging Center. When we click the button the messaging center send from shared code will subscribe to my camera custom Render and picture taking action will happen.

The problem I am facing is the subscribing part of the Messaging center will hit multiple times. The weird thing is the subscribing will increase each time when we click the button. I added the Unsubscribe messaging center. Then it will no longer hit. What will be the cause of this problem? Any help is appreciated.

**My shared code Portion where messaging center send.**

```
private async void Capture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                            
                MessagingCenter.Send<CameraPopup>(this, "CaptureClick");
                            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
```

**Messeging center subscribing portion on android Camera Custom render**

```
  protected async override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Centraverse.Views.Clocking.CustomCamera.CameraPreview> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
                    SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
    
                    // This portion hitting multiple times
                    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CameraPopup>(this,"CaptureClick", (sender) =>
                    {
                        
                        try
                        {
                            Log.Info("Reached here:","Try catch of first ");
                            if (DetectedFaceCount == 0)
                            {
                                //Do Action
                            }
                            else if (DetectedFaceCount == 1)
                            {                           
                                Control.Preview.StopFaceDetection();
                                Task.Run(() => takepicture());
                            }
                            else if (DetectedFaceCount > 1)
                            {
                              //Do Action
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
    
                     //  MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<CameraPopup>(this, "CaptureClick");
    
                    });
                }
                if (e.OldElement != null)
                {
                }
                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);
    
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {                                          
                                Control.Preview.SetFaceDetectionListener(this);
                                Control.Preview.StartFaceDetection();                                    
                        });
    
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                   
                }
    
            }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in OnElementChanged and check how many times it is actually triggered. Maybe you are subscribing multiple times? Otherwise you might have accidentally hooked up the Capture_Tapped even multiple times.

Comment: @Cheesebaron OnElementChanged  only called once when my camera page is loaded

Comment: But will it disappear and be shown again? Or does the multiple triggering occur immediately?

Comment: @Cheesebaron  Bro Intially when we click button , everything works fine. The problem happens after second time.   The 'MessagingCenter.Subscribe' will hit twice on second button click.. And it will become three times when we click the button again

Comment: Have you considered putting your subscription to the messenger in the constructor instead of `OnElementChanged`? Also, not your bro.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Ok let me try that. and sorry for calling that

Comment: @Cheesebaron I tried to place the subscription on constructor. But no change

Comment: That must mean that `Capture_Tapped` must be triggered multiple times. Where does that method get hooked up?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Its in my content page. Its simply a button

Comment: Need more information to be able to help. If you set a breakpoint in the subscription, you should be able to follow the stack trace and figure out what is calling it multiple times and why. Also don't mark your methods async if there is no async code inside of them.

Comment: @Cheesebaron When I put  "Log.Info("")' Inside my subscription, The message gets printed 2 times. But I am only clicking the button once.

Comment: @Cheesebaron  In this case should I need to unsubscribe ?

Comment: Try to put the unsubscribe method before the 'subscribe', try the code like: `protected async override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Centraverse.Views.Clocking.CustomCamera.CameraPreview> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control == null)
    {
        cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
        SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<CameraPopup>(this, "CaptureClick");
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CameraPopup>(this, "CaptureClick", (sender) =>
        {
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
}`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and to the code there can be just one reason for this - you are subscribing multiple times to the event. So you need to unsubscribe first or to have some internal tracking mechanism that you have subscribed and to do it just once.